# Can anyone guide me on the order of execution in this peice of Javascript code? Also, how is it that posts gets a deep copy of this.state.posts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

Can anyone guide me on the order of execution in this piece of JavaScript code? Also, how is it that posts gets a deep copy of `this.state.posts`?

```
handleDelete = async (post) => {
    const posts = this.state.posts;
    this.setState({posts: this.state.posts.filter((p) => p.id !== post.id)});

    try {
        await Axios.delete(endPoint + '/' + post.id);
    } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
        this.setState({posts});
    }
};
```

Comment: what led you to conclude that *posts gets a deep copy of this.state.posts*? is this `react` by the way?

Comment: ahh, it is reactjs - that explains everything

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, its reactJS. Can you please explain?

Comment: Why did you answer my second unimportant question but not the important one. 

    what led you to conclude that posts gets a deep copy of this.state.posts?

Comment: @JaromandaX I logged posts after setState(line 3). It contains the deleted post as well. I figure this is because filter creates a new array and after setState, this.state.posts now points to the new array, while posts points to the old one.
That explains why i mistakenly assumed that posts got a deep copy.

But my question is not only about deep copy. It is also about the order of execution. SetState is asynchronous and so is Axios.delete(). Could you explain the order of execution?